# Append a radio option by using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to append a radio option in the blade. I have some classes in my table. The classes have  level and for different age group. If I choose this class, I may have youth and adult 2 age group. If I choose another class, I may only can choose youth class, etc. So, this is the javascript of the view.

```
$('input[name="class[class_id]"]').change(function () {
  var class_id = $('input[name="class[class_id]"]:checked').val();
  $.ajax({
         url: '{{ route('open.enrollment.course.fee.search', ['code' => $course->url_code]) }}',
         type: 'GET',
         data: {
              'class_id': class_id
         },
         success: function(data) {
         if(data.length == 1){
             var $div = $('#age_group');
             $radio = $('<input />', {
                  id: 'age_group' + data[0].age_group,
                  name: 'age_group',
                  type: "radio",
                  value: data[0].age_group,
             });
             $label = $('<label />', {
                 for: 'age_group' + data[0].age_group,
                    text: label
              });
              $div.append($label).append($radio);
              //append 1 option
          }else{
              //append 2 option
          }

          //want to create radio options like below
          // <option value='youth' data-fee='100'>Youth</option>
          // <option value='adult' data-fee='200'>Adult</option>

          //listener radio

    }
});
```

And here is the html view:

```
<div class="row form-group">
   <label for="age_group" class=" col-sm-2 text-right control-label col-form-label required-field">
        {{ __('table.course_level_fees.age_group') }}
   </label>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio col-5 custom-control-inline" id="age_group">
       //show radio option
   </div>
</div>
```

So the above code is not work. Is there anyone can help me? Thanks so much!

Comment: You can add it to HTML and hide it via CSS, then when you need it you can simply find in DOM and show it.

Comment: what doesn't work here ? does html which you create under success function of ajax doesn't gets appended to div ?

Comment: I just tried you code and it's working. The only line that I had to change was this one `text: label`. What is **label**? A variable? A parameter?